# How to schedule an apex batch job at the end of each quarter

Tags: apex, batch

I want to write a cron expression to schedule a batch job at the end of each quarter i.e. 31st March,30th June,30th Sep and 31st Dec but unable to figure out how to do so.
Has anyone done so ?

Comment: You already have an answer, but this would be helpful for you in the future. https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, if you want to schedule a batch job to run at 11:59 PM on the last day of every quarter, you can use the following cron expression:

> 0 59 23 L 3,6,9,12 ?

This means:

•  0 seconds

•  59 minutes

•  23 hours

•  Last day of the month

•  March, June, September, and December

•  Any day of the week

•  Any year

You can use the `System.schedule` method to schedule the job using the cron expression and the name of the schedulable class. For example:

```
System.schedule('Quarterly Batch Job', '0 59 23 L 3,6,9,12 ?', new QuarterlyBatchJob());
```